# Clicking a Flash-Button using selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, flash, automation

I'm working on a script which is supposed to download something like 3000 files for me. I've worked my way through log-ins and all that stuff but the actual download button = "Extract Data" is written in flash (the rest of the website isn't) is there a way to click this button using selenium? I'm running Python 3.4. on OSx.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import re
import requests

url = "http://www.votewatch.eu/signin.php? 
return_path=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.votewatch.eu%2Fen%2Fterm8-protocol-to- 
the-eu-uzbekistan-partnership-and-cooperation-agreement-accession-of- 
croatia-draft-legis.html" #TestURL

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"/Users/mypath/Desktop/Uni 
/ChromeDriver/ChromeDriver") #Chrome Driver 
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)
elem1 = driver.find_element_by_name("login_username") 
elem1.clear()
elem1.send_keys("my_username")
elem2 = driver.find_element_by_name("login_password") 
elem2.send_keys("mypassword") 
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
login_click = driver.find_element_by_class_name("blue_button_link") 
login_click.click()
extract_data_button = ??????? Flash magic ?????
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: selenium doesn't support flash

Comment: I've actually found a way to solve it by now. I used the developer chrome tools on the button to identify its class_name.